# Enums in separate file are not transpiled

Tags: typescript, enums

I have angular 1.x app. App is build using gulp. I have my enums defined in separate file which is auto-generated, and it's called enums.ts

Content is as follows:

```
declare module MyApp.App {
export enum Status { 
    Done = 0, 
    Unsuccessful = 1, 
    Pending = 2,
}
```

Class which uses this enum is in different file class.ts

```
namespace MyApp.App {    
  export class ResourcesCtrl implements IResourcesCtrl {
      public loading: boolean;
      public resources: IResource[];

      public isSucessfull(resource: IResource): boolean {
          return resource.status.toString() !== Status.Done.toString();
      }
  }

   angular.module("app").
      controller("resourcesCtrl",ResourcesCtrl);
}
```

File is processed by ts compiler, but output js file is always empty.

If I move enum to file which contains class which uses it, everything works fine.

```
namespace MyApp.App {
  export enum Status { 
      Done = 0, 
      Unsuccessful = 1, 
      Pending = 2,
  }

  export class ResourcesCtrl implements IResourcesCtrl {
      public loading: boolean;
      public resources: IResource[];

      public isSucessfull(resource: IResource): boolean {
          return resource.status.toString() !== Status.Done.toString();
      }
  }

   angular.module("app").
      controller("resourcesCtrl",ResourcesCtrl);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't implementation code, it's an ambient declaration.

It starts `declare`... which means it provides information about types only.

If you intend to get output from this file, it needs at least one bit of implementation code.

For example, the following code...

```
declare module DoesNotExist {
    export enum AmbientEnum {
        a, b, c
    }
}

export enum RealEnum {
    d, e, f
}
```

Will only result in an output file with `RealEnum`:

```
define(["require", "exports"], function (require, exports) {
    "use strict";
    Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
    var RealEnum;
    (function (RealEnum) {
        RealEnum[RealEnum["d"] = 0] = "d";
        RealEnum[RealEnum["e"] = 1] = "e";
        RealEnum[RealEnum["f"] = 2] = "f";
    })(RealEnum = exports.RealEnum || (exports.RealEnum = {}));
});
```

Comment: I've updated my question. Could you be so kind to explain why this enum does not get generated. For me, syntax is the same but it does not work when content is split into two separate files

Comment: You still have `declare` in your question. `declare module MyApp.App `. It is the `declare` keyword that tells the compiler the type is informational, rather than an implementation.